# Book series involving a girl who received an omen that she would kill the love of her life if she kissed him

Tags: story-identification, books

I read it long time ago, but one of the main characters was a girl who got an omen that she would kill the love of her life if she kissed him. It also involved a group of boys who went to an all-boys school and had some powers? One of the boys was a ghost? Something like that. :D

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series and/or how many of them you read?

Comment: If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 9):

Is this ***[The Raven Cycle](https://www.goodreads.com/series/73675-the-raven-cycle)*** series by Maggie Stiefvater...?

- Book 1: *[The Raven Boys](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17675462-the-raven-boys)* (2012)
- Book 2: *[The Dream Thieves](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17347389-the-dream-thieves)* (2013)
- Book 3: *[Blue Lily, Lily Blue](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17378508-blue-lily-lily-blue)* (2014)
- Book 4: *[The Raven King](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17378527-the-raven-king)* (2016)

From a [review](https://torontopubliclibrary.typepad.com/teens/2018/07/teen-review-the-raven-cycle-by-maggie-stiefvater.html):

> The Raven Cycle is a young adult fantasy series written by Maggie Stiefvater. The series consists of The Raven Boys, The Dream Thieves, Blue Lily Lily Blue, and The Raven King. **These books take place in the small town of Henrietta, Virginia, which is best known for its prestigious, all-boys school called Aglionby Academy.** It is a school for the sons of businessmen, politicians, and generally the filthy rich.**The students of the school have been nicknamed “raven boys” by local, average citizens.**
>
> **One of those average citizens happens to be a teenage girl by the name of Blue Sargent, who comes from a family of psychics.** Everyone in her life is gifted with the powers of both insight and foresight, which makes it quite strange that Blue herself isn’t blessed with either. **Even though she doesn’t have any psychic abilities of her own, everyone around her has always made the exact same prediction of her future -- that if she were to kiss her true love, he would die.** Having this prediction looming over her entire life, this makes her sensible enough to stay away from boys. After all, she can’t fall in love with them if they’re never around.

[Another review](https://thestorysanctuary.com/book-review-the-raven-boys-by-maggie-stiefvater/) mentions the involvement of a male ghost in the story:

> Blue’s mother and her friends use psychic ability to make their living and to predict what will happen in Blue’s life and the lives of her friends. Much of the story centers around belief in these abilities and in magic, spirits and rituals. **Blue and her friends befriend a ghost and help him maintain a presence.** Blue is gifted with the ability to strengthen psychic energy.